# How to best compare two NSString objects while ignoring case?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to compare two strings. It fails when the string have capital letter. How do I convert both string to capitalize and compare.

I have a sample code, can someone correct this.

```
if ([[txtAnswer.text capitalizedString] isEqualToString:[answer capitalizedString]]) {
     // Do somehing
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean it fails when you have capital letter

Comment: this should work — assuming `txtAnswer.text` and `answer` are NSStrings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at [the `NSString` class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsstring_Class/Reference/NSString.html) you will see under the heading *Identifying and Comparing Strings* the methods [`caseInsensitiveCompare:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsstring_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/caseInsensitiveCompare%3a) and [`localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsstring_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare%3a).

Answer (score 6):

You might try something like:

```
if ([txtAnswer.text caseInsensitiveCompare: answer] == NSOrderedSame) {
 // do something.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do a case insensitive string compare.

```
if([txtAnswer.text compare:answer options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame)
{
    // Do somehing
}
```